# Coverity - Explicit null dereferenced (FORWARD_NULL) in contentResolver.delete()

Tags: android, static-analysis, coverity

Deleting all the rows from ContentProvider using delete() statement gives the Coverity error.

**Explicit null dereferenced (FORWARD_NULL)**
**Passing null pointer selection to delete, which dereferences it.**

```
String selection = null;
String[] selectionArgs = null;

mContentResolver.delete(MyContentProvider.MY_CONTENT_URI, selection, selectionArgs);
```

Is there any way to fix this Coverity issue ??

Comment: Show us your `ContentProvider.delete` code and full logcat please :)

Comment: @zozelfelfo This is not build error. Statement works fine and deletes all the rows as expected when executed. This error is shown in the Coverity static analysis tool.

Comment: How about reporting the issue to Coverity?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to your code the issue seems right - you forward "null"... Can you post the code of your ContentResolver Implementation?

To remove the warning you may try to use:

```
String selection = "";
String[] selectionArgs = new String[0];
```

As you may see in the [source code](http://grepcode.com/file/repository.grepcode.com/java/ext/com.google.android/android/4.4.4_r1/android/content/ContentResolver.java#ContentResolver.delete%28android.net.Uri%2Cjava.lang.String%2Cjava.lang.String[]%29) the selection (at least) for logging is set to:

```
selection != null ? selection : "",
```

Comment: I also ended up doing the same for removing the warning.. Thanks for the answer.